# Checking for Duplicates in a DataFrame when certain cells contain a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a List of dictionaries. In the dictionaries there is a variable `Attachments`. `Attachments` can either contain the Boolean `False` or a list:

```
[{'Topic': 'Project-Monument', 'Description': 'English Project Monument', 'Attachments': False, 'Set- 
Date': Timestamp('2020-06-24 00:00:00'), 'Subject': 'English', 'Due-Date': Timestamp('2020-07-27 
00:00:00')}, {'Topic': 'Sanskrit 3rd language', 'Description': 'Sanskrit homework', 'Attachments': 
[ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='eduflex.co.in', path='/portal/custom/THEDEENS/assignments/VIII- 
A/20200724/Grade_-_8_Lesson-1_Practice_worksheet_1.pdf', params='', query='', fragment='')], 'Set- 
Date': Timestamp('2020-07-24 00:00:00'), 'Subject': '-Sanskrit', 'Due-Date': Timestamp('2020-07-27 
00:00:00')}]
```

This is what a normal dataframe declared with `new_homeworks = pd.DataFrame(extracted_homeworks)` looks like:

```
In [20]: normal_df
Out[20]:
                   Topic               Description                                        Attachments   Set-Date    Subject   Due-Date
0       Project-Monument  English Project Monument                                              False 2020-06-24    English 2020-07-27
1  Sanskrit 3rd language         Sanskrit homework  [(https, eduflex.co.in, /portal/custom/THEDEEN... 2020-07-24  -Sanskrit 2020-07-27
```

I also declared it with `json_df = json_normalize(extracted_homework)` (I wrote the same question before and someone suggested that)

I also declared it like this:

```
astype_df = pd.DataFrame(extracted_homeworks).astype("object")
```

This gave me the following datatypes:

```
In [25]: astype_df.dtypes
Out[25]:
Topic          object
Description    object
Attachments    object
Set-Date       object
Subject        object
Due-Date       object
dtype: object
```

Now when I tried check for duplicates:

```
In [27]: normal_df.duplicated(subset = None).any()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-dc58355eb3fc> in <module>
----> 1 normal_df.duplicated(subset = None).any()

c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in duplicated(self, subset, keep)
   4886
   4887         vals = (col.values for name, col in self.items() if name in subset)
-> 4888         labels, shape = map(list, zip(*map(f, vals)))
   4889
   4890         ids = get_group_index(labels, shape, sort=False, xnull=False)

c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in f(vals)
   4860
   4861         def f(vals):
-> 4862             labels, shape = algorithms.factorize(
   4863                 vals, size_hint=min(len(self), _SIZE_HINT_LIMIT)
   4864             )

c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in factorize(values, sort, na_sentinel, size_hint)
    633             na_value = None
    634
--> 635         codes, uniques = _factorize_array(
    636             values, na_sentinel=na_sentinel, size_hint=size_hint, na_value=na_value
    637         )

c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in _factorize_array(values, na_sentinel, size_hint, na_value)
    482
    483     table = hash_klass(size_hint or len(values))
--> 484     uniques, codes = table.factorize(values, na_sentinel=na_sentinel, na_value=na_value)
    485
    486     codes = ensure_platform_int(codes)

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.factorize()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable._unique()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Same thing with all the other DFs.
So, I went had a look at [The pandas.DataFrame.duplicated() site](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)
I saw only to Parameters : subset, and keep. Which I felt had nothing with Hashing
However I saw mention of hashable at subset: Union

Could someone suggset a way around this? I also had the same issue with Beautifulsoup objects.
Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case it's just a simple case of `explode()` the list before you check for duplicates.  Core python - lists are not hashable and so breaks `duplicate()` function.

```
from pandas import Timestamp
from urllib.parse import ParseResult
data = [{'Topic': 'Project-Monument', 'Description': 'English Project Monument', 'Attachments': False, 
  'Set-Date': Timestamp('2020-06-24 00:00:00'), 'Subject': 'English', 'Due-Date': Timestamp('2020-07-27 00:00:00')}, 
 {'Topic': 'Sanskrit 3rd language', 'Description': 'Sanskrit homework', 'Attachments': 
[ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='eduflex.co.in', path='/portal/custom/THEDEENS/assignments/VIII-A/20200724/Grade_-_8_Lesson-1_Practice_worksheet_1.pdf', params='', query='', fragment='')], 
  'Set-Date': Timestamp('2020-07-24 00:00:00'), 'Subject': '-Sanskrit', 'Due-Date': Timestamp('2020-07-27 00:00:00')}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.explode("Attachments").duplicated(subset=None).any()
```